# sqlite3 selecting all 1:n values from an n:n table

Tags: sqlite, group-by, count, distinct, having

I have an sqlite table that relates 2 entities, in the form

```
x | y
1   1
1   3
2   2
2   3
3   1
3   2
3   3
```

Expected output: 3
(because x=3 links to y=1,2,3, aka all values of y)

I need to select all values in x that have a relation to every value in y
My issue is that when I group by x, then check how many y-values there are for a given group of x's,
I don't know how many y values there are total because I just grouped my table by x's and can't access the original one to count.

Comment: show what you expect the output to be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this query:

```
SELECT x
FROM tablename
GROUP BY x
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT y) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT y) FROM tablename);
```

you can get get all the `x` that are related to every `y`.

You can use it with the operator `IN` to get all the rows from the table:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE x IN (
  SELECT x
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY x
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT y) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT y) FROM tablename) 
);
```

If there are no duplicate combinations of `x` and `y`, the `HAVING` clause can be written simpler:

```
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT y) FROM tablename)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=904d70364c3bce32f27eea342b2dcc1a).